# Fixing a windows boot error on another drive

Tags: windows-10, grub, bootloader, dualboot, system-reserved-partition

Here is the situation: A few days ago, I tried to dual boot linux, and had to end up uninstalling it. I thought that simply deleting the partition in which I installed it would be good enough, but now I realized that it was a big mistake and I kept entering grub rescue mode when I booted and couldn't access any of my files.

I tried all the easy fixes I could find online, but none of them worked for me. But I remembered I had a second (mostly unused) hard drive in my pc, so I installed windows onto that so that I can at least have access to all the files, applications, etc. on my SSD.

Now I am wondering if there is a way to fix the grub problem on boot up for the ssd while keeping all files and the windows installation on it intact. All drives are healthy, I just need to get around the grub problem.

Additional info:

I assumed that the partition grub was still installed on was the system reserved partition in my SSD, and that installing windows on my hard drive would make a separate system reserved partition, but I couldn't see it when I launched the disk manager.

And when I looked into the system reserved  partition, there was nothing inside efi/mictosoft/boot. But this was just through file explorer, so I wouldn't know if there were hidden files

Also, if it is possible to transfer the windows license from the ssd to the hard drive, that could also be helpful if I can't get rid of grub.

Comment: "is possible to transfer the windows license from the ssd to the hard drive" - Yes; Just reinstall Windows on the HDD.  Windows will automatically activate.

Comment: @Ramhound reinstall? I already installed windows on the HDD and I have the home edition running, but I had pro running on my SSD so I don't think it transferred properly. did you mean to say SSD?

Comment: How you install Windows 10 Professional, on a machine which came with Windows 10 Home is well documented, I have answered that question several times.  It involves editing a text file on the ISO, which allows you to install Professional, avoiding the mechanism that automatically installs Home.  You can also upgrade Home to Professional provided you have the license key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using UEFI then just press F12 ( key may be different ) to access boot menu and select windows boot manager . You can change boot order from UEFI firmware settings.

Not sure in your case but windows generally adds boot menu for other previously installed windows automatically if detected properly . So check if there are another entries if not then follow these steps to add one . Also make sure boot menu timeout is set to some value.

You can add a new boot menu in your current windows boot manager for your previously installed window simply :

```
 1. run cmd as admin 
        
 2. type -
```

> Bcdboot D:\Windows

```
  where replace D with the drive letter of that disk
```

After that a new boot menu will be added and you can boot from that drive after reboot

**If none of them fixes then**

boot from win installation USB

> 1. Repair your PC
> 2. Advanced troubleshooting
> 3. command prompt

and run

```
 diskpart
 
 sel disk n (where n is number of that disk)
 
 list vol
```

Verify that the EFI partition (EPS - EFI System Partition) is using the FAT32 file system. Assign a drive letter to it that is not already in use:

```
sel vol <number of volume>

assign letter=<drive letter>:

exit
```

In order to repair the boot record:

```
cd /d <drive letter>:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\

bootrec /FixBoot
```

**If using MBR**

> 1. Repair your PC
> 2. Advanced troubleshooting
> 3. command prompt

Enter the following three commands in turn, following each by pressing the Enter key:

> bootrec /fixmbr
>
> bootrec /fixboot
>
> bootrec /rebuildbcd

Restart the PC with the installation media removed to check if the repair worked

Comment: This was exactly one of the solutions that followed, but it didn't work since bootrec/fixboot gave me an access denies error. Solutions to that problem also failed

Comment: Actually your first method just worked! I guess it never hurts to try again :)

Comment: Bcdboot D:\Windows did the trick! You just saved my life!